# WCF update service reference issue

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a wcf service where I do some business specific processes. I using the "update service reference" to generate the proxy file. previously, my function will be like this:

```
dim proxy = new proxyReference
proxy.login(loginId, loginpwd)
```

My login function receive 2 string parameters which are `loginId` and `loginPwd` and returns a  boolean value.

But recently it became

```
dim proxy = new proxyReference
proxy.login(loginRequest)
```

It takes only one parameter of type `loginRequest` and returns a `loginResponse` object. I really have no idea, can some WCF expert help with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: If you maintain both the service and the client, "Service Reference" is not the recommended way to do this. I would recommend that you extract the interfaces into a separate assembly that is shared between both the service and the client.

Answer (score 0):

Who maintains the service?

Possibly your service contracts got updated and is using a different input and return parameters.

Or else you might be facing the same issue as mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b9655eeb-cdbb-4703-87d8-00deac340173/add-service-reference-creates-message-contracts-requestresponse-objects-with-always-generate?forum=wcf)

*Looks like it is using message contract instead of data contract.
You can right click on the service reference, select "Configure Service Reference..." and make sure that the option "Always generate message contracts" is unchecked.*

*Take a look at your message contract and make sure that both (Request and Response) are marked like [MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)]*

Comment: I think not, the service is maintained by me , the contract no changing anything.  Not only login function , other function changing the parameter to xxxRequest and xxxRespinse too.